# SetThreadExecutionState(ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED) does not turn the screen back on

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script to run a few tasks in order to test the batteries on a wide range of tablet PCs.

A big part of this is controlling the display. I don't seem to have too much trouble turning it off, but when I come to turn it back on again, it only seems to work on some machines.

I have found this very helpful code:

```
#Load the Windows API from a specified dll - here Kernel32.dll
$function=@' 
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,SetLastError = true)]
 public static extern void SetThreadExecutionState(uint esFlags);
'@

$method = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $function -name System -namespace Win32 -passThru 

#Specify the flags to use them later 
$ES_CONTINUOUS = [uint32]'0x80000000'
$ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = [uint32]'0x00000040'
$ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = [uint32]'0x00000002'
$ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = [uint32]'0x00000001'

$method::SetThreadExecutionState($ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED)
```

This will work fine on about 60% of the machines I try, but not the rest...

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please elaborate on "work fine" and "not" working fine? How do you turn off the display in the first place? What happens in 40% of the cases when you run the code? Display remains off? Turns on briefly and then back off?

Comment: Apologies. 

works fine = the screen does turn back on when the above code is executed. 

Not working fine (40% of the machines) = the screen does not turn back on, and the code appears to wait, or stall. I think this is because the tablet is in a sleep mode of some sort...? Screen doesn't flash on, just remains blank.

Comment: I use this code to turn the display off  https://gist.github.com/oledid/fb02951b6b1848d1418d